# Question - Scale Animation Error?

Tags: animation, game-engine

Could someone explain to me why this happened?
Create an animation using 'Scale' and put the animation on the other object on the left and look what happened.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please explain what the result you're seeing is (it's hard to tell from images what the animation is doing) and then explain how it differs from the intended result.

Comment: Is this really blender game engine related?

Comment: I created an animation in a 'plane.001' and did the configuration in 'Logic Bricks'.
Then I created another object 'plane.002' and in the settings in 'Logic Bricks' I used the same animation as 'plane.001'. When I run the 'game' the animation of plane.002 gets irregular. It imitates the point of origin of the plane.001 ...

Comment: _"the animation of plane.002 gets irregular. It imitates the point of origin of the plane.001"_, if im not wrong, i think its relate to the origin of the animation, when you animate something it has to be in the center of the scene, when you animate something that is not in the center it works only for the first animated object, and the others objects just get on the wrong place.

Comment: Could you guide me to solve it? Do I need to put the object in the center of the scene and then create the animation? Thank you!